# Simple code that finds number of factors crashes my computer. Is there a workaround for a large number?

Tags: python, project-euler

This is my attempt at [problem 12 from Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=12). However, my code freezes my old, linux computer when I run it. I've only got 512MB of RAM and an old Intel Core 2 Duo processor on my machine which, I assume, is why it can't run the code.

Is there a way to optimize this code without using up too much resources?

```
#!/bin/python

def nth_triangle_number(nth):
    """ Sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. 
        So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. """
    return sum([i for i in range(nth+1)]) 

def get_number_of_factors(num):                 
    quantity = 0
    for i in range(1, int(num/2)+1):     # I think the problem lies here in range()
        if not num % i:                  # BTW, using math.sqrt() produces the wrong
            quantity += 1                # answer for smaller numbers. I don't know why.
    return quantity + 1     # Added 1 to count for num (as in 1 * num)

def get_triangle_number(divisors):
    """ Find the triangle number with the given amount of divisors """
    i = 1
    while get_number_of_factors(nth_triangle_number(i)) <= divisors:
        i += 1

    return nth_triangle_number(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    number_of_divisors = 500
    print "Answer found: ", get_triangle_number(number_of_divisors)
```

I've tried initializing get_triangle_number(), i, at higher values, but it didn't seem to help. I believe the problem is with get_number_of_factors(). I had originally stored all the factors of a given integer into a list then compared its length to number_of_divisors. I figured counting each integer that satisfied the condition would save some resources.

The code does run properly and produces the correct answer when I tested the example provided on [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=12) and the following values:

```
    number_of_divisors = 5      # Runs properly and produces correct answer
    number_of_divisors = 50     # Runs properly and         "    "
    number_of_divisors = 150    # Runs properly and         "    "
    number_of_divisors = 200    # Crash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can easily find the bottleneck in your code by running it with the profiler (ran with `number_of_divisors = 100`):

```
~> python -m cProfile t.py
Answer found:  73920
         1926 function calls in 0.522 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.522    0.522 t.py:1(<module>)
      385    0.006    0.000    0.008    0.000 t.py:1(nth_triangle_number)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.522    0.522 t.py:13(get_triangle_number)
      384    0.472    0.001    0.514    0.001 t.py:6(get_number_of_factors)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
      769    0.043    0.000    0.043    0.000 {range}
      385    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {sum}
```

You can immediately see that:

1. Indeed, `get_number_of_factors()` slows everything down;
2. You can slightly optimize things by replacing `range` with `xrange` (which does not create a list).

In your case `get_number_of_factors()` is a good example of a function that requires algorithmic optimization. Currently it has O(N) complexity. As you correctly guessed, iterating only till `sqrt(num)` will make it faster:

```
def get_number_of_factors(num):

    limit = math.sqrt(num)
    int_sqrt = int(round(limit))

    if int_sqrt ** 2 == num:
        int_limit = int_sqrt
        quantity = 1
    else:
        int_limit = int(limit) + 1
        quantity = 0

    for i in xrange(1, int_limit):
        if not num % i:
            quantity += 2

    return quantity
```

Some highlights:

1. `math.sqrt` returns a float, so if you want to be extra-safe, you need to convert it to integer properly (if `sqrt(4)` gives you `3.9999999`, just `int()` will produce `3`).
2. When you are iterating to the square root, each factor you found stands for two factors: `i` and `num / i`.
3. But you do not want to include the root itself, because if `num` is a perfect root, you only need to count `sqrt(num)` once.

This makes your algorithm run in O(sqrt(N)). 
**Edit**: if you want even more performance, you can try to implement [number field sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve).

To add more performance, you can replace the direct sum in `nth_triangle_number()` with a known formula for arithmetic progression.
The result is:

```
import math

def nth_triangle_number(nth):
    """ Sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers.
        So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28.
        Using the fact that 1 + ... + n = n * (n + 1) / 2
        """
    return nth * (nth + 1) / 2

def get_number_of_factors(num):

    limit = math.sqrt(num)
    int_sqrt = int(round(limit))

    if int_sqrt ** 2 == num:
        int_limit = int_sqrt
        quantity = 1
    else:
        int_limit = int(limit) + 1
        quantity = 0

    for i in xrange(1, int_limit):
        if not num % i:
            quantity += 2

    return quantity

def get_triangle_number(divisors):
    """ Find the triangle number with the given amount of divisors """
    i = 1
    while get_number_of_factors(nth_triangle_number(i)) <= divisors:
        i += 1

    return nth_triangle_number(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    number_of_divisors = 100
    print "Answer found: ", get_triangle_number(number_of_divisors)
```

And it runs much faster now. For `100`:

```
~> python -m cProfile t.py 
Answer found:  73920
         1540 function calls in 0.007 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.007    0.007 t.py:1(<module>)
      384    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 t.py:10(get_number_of_factors)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.006 t.py:28(get_triangle_number)
      385    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 t.py:3(nth_triangle_number)
      384    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {math.sqrt}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
      384    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {round}
```

And for `500`:

```
~> python -m cProfile t.py 
Answer found:  76576500
         49504 function calls in 5.364 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.364    5.364 t.py:1(<module>)
    12375    5.342    0.000    5.349    0.000 t.py:10(get_number_of_factors)
        1    0.010    0.010    5.363    5.363 t.py:28(get_triangle_number)
    12376    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 t.py:3(nth_triangle_number)
    12375    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {math.sqrt}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    12375    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {round}
```

Comment: Excellent! So much useful information in your review! I especially like the algorithms you've introduced. I'm at the end my first year in my CS course and I have yet to explore this stuff. Thanks for the head start!